# Orange textmining

Tags: database, data-mining, text-mining, orange

I am using Orange datamining software to try and look at data in a text file and see if I can discover anything. When I add the text-file, it asks for a .app file. I do not know how to convert a text document, or even export a database into a .app file. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you specify what exact steps you want to perform? The format Orange usually uses is ".tab" (see http://orange.biolab.si/datasets.psp).

Answer (score 1):

Orange takes .tab (Tab delimited files) as input. The first row includes the name of the class(es) and feature(s), the second row is the type of the classes and features either d (for discrete) or c (for continuous or numeric). The third row has the label "class" for each class in your database.

Refer to its documentation for more details and sample http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/tutorial/rst/data/

Answer (score 1):

I usualy use [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) to convert any **text/Excel** file in a ".tab" file by clicking on the up-right **Export** button and chose "Tab-Separated Values", and then I rename the imported file in "*.tab" and then I import it in Orange.

[image: Export as TSV from OpenRefine]